# Property bags as site custom fields: are them accessible by webparts?

Tags: site, react, react-webpart, property-bag

I'm trying to figure out how to setup site custom fields, to be retrieved from React webparts.

Doing some research, I've found several articles talking about Property Bags, like [this one](https://prairiedeveloper.com/2023/02/sharepoint-online-the-property-bag-what-is-it-and-how-to-configure-it/) which seems satisfying my needs, but my question is: supposing to setup a property bag for a site (PowerShell is the only way?), is then retrievable by webparts deployed on that site?

Could you please give me an example/link, on how to retrieve this information in a React Webpart?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/add-and-retrieve-property-bag-values-in-sharepoint-using-javascript-object-model/ And: https://prairiedeveloper.com/2023/02/sharepoint-online-the-property-bag-what-is-it-and-how-to-configure-it/

Comment: Thanks @MartinIszac: the first link seems a little old and in plain JS (no React) and the second one is the same I posted in my question...

Comment: As admin, is it possible to create a property bag via web interface on a tenant?

Comment: There is a pnpcore open source library, and they do web properties:
https://pnp.github.io/pnpcore/using-the-sdk/webs-intro.html#web-property-bag  
so maybe looking at the code behind you can get some ideas...

Comment: Also - maybe this workaround can help - instead of getting properties for a specific site you might get sites where this property is set up to specific value. The last is possible when a property is setup as indexed, and at search service you mapped crawled property to refinable string and you use search api with an $entityTypes = "['site']" and query like "* refinablestring125='myvalue'"